# Trying to filter out any instances that contain the word thumb from a variable

Tags: php

This is part of a script that grabs all files from a folder, filters out the image files, and then displays them. I would like to remove any instances in $names variable that contain the word "thumb" before it begins to filter by extension.

```
sort($names);


$tempvar=0;
for ($i=0;$names[$i];$i++){
$ext=strtolower(substr($names[$i],-4));
if ($ext==".jpg"||$ext==".gif"||$ext=="jpeg"||$ext==".png"){$names1[$tempvar]=$names[$i];$tempvar++;}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [`fnmatch` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tempvar=0;
for ($i=0;$names[$i];$i++){

  if(strpos($names[$i], 'thumb') === false){

    $ext=strtolower(substr($names[$i],-4));
    if ($ext==".jpg"||$ext==".gif"||$ext=="jpeg"||$ext==".png"){ 
        $names1[$tempvar]=$names[$i];$tempvar++;}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a for loop, where you could use a (simpler) foreach instead. Any reason you're not using a simple array_filter? This would make the code easier to read (to me, anyway):

```
<?php
$names = array(
    'foo.thumb.jpg',
    'bar.jpg',
    'bar.THUMB.jpg',
    'qux.png',
    'README.TXT'
);

$extensions = array( 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png' );

$filtered = array_filter( $names, function( $name ) use ( $extensions ) {
    if( stripos( $name, 'thumb' ) !== false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return in_array( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $extensions );
});

var_dump( $filtered );
```

Also, instead of `substr($names[$i], -4 )`, I've opted for using pathinfo. This way, the extensions may be of any lenght, and will always be returned correctly.